# PHP website shows question marks insted of utf-8 characters although in Netbeans it's saved in utf-8

Tags: php, netbeans, encoding, utf-8

I have a PHP website written in Netbeans. It contains meta:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

and header:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

also all 3 other PHP files responsible for changing a language of the site contains this header. I've found here information that it could be due to Netbeans not saving files in UTF-8. So I added

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

in netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf file. But problem still exists. What can be the problem now? Website looked ok, when it was html. After adding posibility of changing language question marks started to show.

Comment: Not sure if related but check: [utf-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: open the file with notepad++ if you can and check if it is utf-8 or utf-8 without BOM. Because with BOM can cause this problem as well. And if you put out data from database check if the data stream uses utf-8 as well

Comment: unfortunately it's utf-8 without BOM and I don't use any database.